# Drawing a Rectangle over multiple frame

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Is it even possible to draw a rectangle over multiple frame?
Let me explain a bit. I have a tall box i wanted draw a rectangle over that box, but the problem the box is too big to fit inside a frame. I know the exact dimension of the box and how far away am from the box. Now i wanted to move my camera from top to bottom so that i can see the full rectangle over the box.

Comment: You can provide `cv::rectangle` with coordinates that are not inside the frame. So just computing the new 2D coordinates of your rectangle after moving the camera and drawing should be ok.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger Could you elaborate a bit

Comment: Is your problem to draw the rectangle, or to compute the coordinates of the box in your image? I'm assuming "box" is a real physical object.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger "Box" is a real physical object. My problem is to draw the rectangle. Sorry if i was not clear in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but these are my two cents.

I assume you have a frame, which is an image in a `cv::Mat`, that shows an object (a box) and you want to draw a rectangle around it. You know the 2D coordinates of the object in your image. Then, you can draw a rectangle like this:

```
cv::rectangle(image, cv::Point(x1, y1), cv::Point(x2, y2), cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0));
```

Where `x1 y1` and `x2 y2` are two opposite corners of the rectangle to show, and the `cv::Scalar` is the color (red if your image is `CV_8UC3`).

When you move the camera, I assume that you recompute the 2D coordinates of your object in the new image. Then, you have to redraw the rectangle again. The final code should be something similar to this:

```
while (true) {
  cv::Mat image = getImageFromCamera();
  cv::Point corner1, corner2;
  computeRectangleCoordinates(corner1, corner2);
  // draw
  cv::rectangle(image, corner1, corner2, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0));
  // display
  cv::imshow("box", image);
  cv::waitKey(5);
}
```

Comment: Thanky you so much for your patients. And for describing my problem poorly

Comment: my object (Box) is much bigger than my frame. i wanted to draw only one rectangle from top of my object till bottom as i move the camera from top to bottom.

Comment: If the coordinates `x1 y1` `x2 y2` are outside the frame, they will not be displayed. If you don't want partial rectangles, check that all the coordinates are `0 <= x < image.cols` and `0 <= y < image.rows`.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is first merge/combine these frames into a larger frame (larger than the box), and then draw the box on this combined frame.

If you need to get each small frame with box drawn, you can further extract the ROI from the combined frame.